# What's the reason behind Venkateshwara's unusual urdhwapundra?

Tags: venkateshwara, tilak

There are two unusual aspects of [Lord Venkateshwara's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara) [Urdhwapundra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdhva_Pundra)

**1) The size of UrdhwaPundra:**

The Urdhwpundra covers more than 30% of Lord's face, while normally it should cover around 10%. The Venkatanchalpati's urdhwapundra doesn't have the Sri Churnam or Red/Yellow part.

**Standard Urdhwapundram for Sri Vaishnavas**
[image: Std Urdhwapundra1]

[image]

**Venkatanchalapti's Urdhwapundra**

[image]

**2) The material used for drawing Urdhwapundra**

In normal cases the Urdhwapundra is made out of Thiruman(special clay) and Red/Yellow part Sri Churnam. The Urdhwapundra on the face of Venkatanchalpati is made out of pachcha kapoor natural/edible camphor.